# PHP ZF2 - How to create dynamic urls

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been tasked to explore the possibilities of creating dynamic urls.
What we try to achieve is serving a domain for the client.

eg. www.example.com/clients/john/

eg. www.example.com/clients/bill/

These urls are not fixed, but have to be made dynamically everytime a Client registers at our site. Our URL's are build of Controllers and Actions. Like www.example.com/controller/action.

How can this be achieved in the PHP Zend Framework 2?

Big thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is the [ZF2 Manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html):

I suggest to use [segment routes](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html#zend-mvc-router-http-segment)
You can define them like:

```
 'client' => array(
    'route' => '/clients/:username',
    'constraints' => array(
        'username' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-]+', //accepted value pattern
    ),
    'defaults' => array( //which action to invoke
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\ClientController',
        'action'     => 'showclient',
    ),
));
```

Then you can create an url with url helper like:

```
$this->url('client', array('username' => 'John'));
```

And in your controller you will be able to get `username` param with:

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('username');
```

Comment: This is definitely a better approach than the above `regex` answer.